# VB extracting average from Access database

Tags: vb.net

Hello and sorry for my noob question. I've been trying to find the answer for hours (including official msdn Microsoft guides) with no positive results.

Currently I'm working on VB.Net Parcel Delivery project which aims to write to and retrieve data from the access database. On display form it displays selected data in Data Grid View, I used the sql query to retrieve only UK entires. I am able to display the number of entries which meet the condition but can't figure out how to run another query so it will calculate average cost of parcels and furthermore how to pass the result into the variable. Can somebody please take a look at this and help? Would approciate advices on how the code could be improved. Please bear in mind I'm at very beggining level.

```
    Private Sub frmUkInfo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source= D:/ProjectDatabase.mdb"
    connect.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    connect.Open()
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)

    sql = "SELECT * FROM Parcels WHERE ParZone = ""UK"""
    dataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connect)
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)

    dataView.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView

    connect.Close()

    rowsNo = dataView.Rows.Count
    lblParcelsNoDisplay.Text = rowsNo

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us an indication of what the error is.

Comment: The only think is I'm not getting any error simply because I don't know how to approach the problem, i.e. get average out of the Cost table in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Linq-To-DataTable` to get the average price:

```
Dim parcelPrices = From row In dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   Select row.Field(Of Double)("Price")
Dim averageCostOfParcels As Double = parcelPrices.Average()
```

Comment: I have tried it and assign the result to label:
        lblAvgCostDisplay.Text = averageCostOfParcels Although in the label nothing displays. Any ideas?

Comment: @JaE: get familiar with the debugger, set a breakpoint and inspect the value of `averageCostOfParcels`. Does the table contain rows at all? What contains the list of prices: `Dim list = parcelPrices.ToList()`?

Comment: I had run debugger. The value of the avarage is 0.0 at all times. The code looks as follows: 'Dim parcelPrices = From row In dataTable.AsEnumerable()
           Select row.Field(Of Double)("Cost")
        Dim averageCostOfParcels As Double = parcelPrices.Average()
        lblAvgCostDisplay.Text = averageCostOfParcels' Changed to "Cost" as it is the name of the table. Also tried replacing Double with Single but got the same result. And yes, the table contains rows and values (5 for UK at the moment). The table in Access file has currency format. Can this matter?

Comment: @JaE: inspect the `DataTable` in the debugger's [`DataTable`-visualization window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d480bk47.aspx). Maybe you have to use `Decimal` instead of `Double` but i doubt that.

Comment: Changing Double to Decimal works. Thank you very much. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Parcels WHERE ParZone = 'UK'"
```